# Set Visual Studio Code to use Dark Theme

Tags: themes

Is it possible to force vs code someway to use dark mode on its title bar, alerts, etc?

I installed it as a snap.

(I've read about wanting devs to opt-in to the new dark theme implementation, but maybe there is a way to do it in the meantime?)

Comment: Install elementary os tweaks and set "force dark theme". It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the custom style to your `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` file:

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom"
```

Comment: Yeah, but it shows windows-like buttons. I would like to have the native title bar black